# Collision between two div vanillaJS no detection

Tags: javascript, html, collision, detection

I created a game for the web in vanilla js. I would like the console to detect a collision between two `<img>` tags. I am using the DOM to retrieve the items. With the arrows, I can move one of the images.

Problem: When they touch each other the console does not detect anything. It's written: no collision. I need the collisions to go to a next page / scene.

```js
console.log('collisions');
// collision entre la limite et le personnage


let rect1 = document.getElementsByClassName('perso')
let rect2 = document.getElementsByClassName('obstacle');
console.log(rect1[0]);
console.log(rect2[0]);

if (rect1[0].x < rect2[0].x + rect2[0].width &&
  rect1[0].x + rect1[0].width > rect2[0].x &&
  rect1[0].y < rect2[0].y + rect2[0].height &&
  rect1[0].height + rect1[0].y > rect2[0].y) {
  console.log("collision");
  // window.location.href = 'htmlpage1.html';//passe à la page/scene suivante
} else {
  console.log("no collision");
}
```

```css
#move {
  height: 300px;
  width: 300px;
  position: relative;
  z-index: 1;
}


/* limite de la page permet de passer à la scene suivante */

#limite {
  width: 150px;
  height: 250px;
  position: fixed;
  z-index: 2;
  margin: 30px 1100px;
  opacity: 50%;
}
```

```html
<main>

  <div class="cadre">
    <img id="premierplan" src="../img/foreground.png" alt="premierplan">
    <img id="move" class="perso" src="../img/ne_bouge_pas_.gif" alt="image personnage">
    <img id="limite" class="obstacle" src="../img/carrebleu.png" class="cube" alt="frontiere">
  </div>

</main>
```

Comment: [getBoundingClientRect](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/getBoundingClientRect)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a few issues..

1. [`getElementsByClassName`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementsByClassName) returns an [`HTMLCollection`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLCollection), not a single element. You need to either iterate over these if you have more than one. Or if there's just one of each class, just use `querySelector`.
2. If you want to use the element's `x`, `y`, you need to get it's [`DOMRect`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/DOMRect) using [`getBoundingClientRect`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/getBoundingClientRect).

Try this instead:

```js
let rect1 = document.querySelector('.perso').getBoundingClientRect();
let rect2 = document.querySelector('.obstacle').getBoundingClientRect();
```

Comment: Thank you I'll try this

Comment: Hello the console shows always "No collision" but shows DOMRect coordonates

Comment: I also tried to set the position to fixed and relative for my div in the css

Comment: @MikaMikashu - I addressed the only issue I could address with the information you gave. You did not provide the full code so I cannot tell you why the collision isn't being detected. I am not clairvoyant.

Comment: Thank you for your help. I will still try by changing the CSS/HTML and I will tell you if I succeed. Have a nice day

Comment: Thanks for helping me, the code works on my other HTML page.It's the CSS that wasn't going well. Have a great evening

Answer (score 0):

I have found the solution to my question. For the code to work, it must be placed in the keydown and keyup function otherwise it will only work once. It was complicated but I got there. So my character can move from one HTML5 scene / page to another. My Javascript code:

```
const RIGHT_KEY = 39;
const LEFT_KEY = 37;
const S_KEY = 83;


document.onkeydown = function(e) { 
    if (e.keyCode == LEFT_KEY) {//si la flêche gauche est pressée
    move.style.left = (move.offsetLeft + -10) + 'px';//aller à gauche
    let gauche = document.getElementsByClassName("perso");//changer l'animation par walk_vers_gauche
        // console.log(gauche);
        gauche[0].src="../img/walk_vers_gauche.gif";
     }
     else if (e.keyCode == RIGHT_KEY) {//si la fleche droites est pressée
        move.style.left = (move.offsetLeft + 10) + 'px';//si la fleche droites est pressée
        let droit = document.getElementsByClassName("perso");//changer l'animation par walk.png
        // console.log(droit);
        droit[0].src="../img/walk.gif";  
    } 
    
    else if(e.keyCode == S_KEY){ //si la touche S est préssée 
        let jump = document.getElementsByClassName("perso");//changer l'animation par saute
        console.log(jump); 
        jump[0].src = "../img/saute.gif";        
    }
    else{
        let stable = document.getElementsByClassName("perso");//sinon jouer animation "ne bouge pas"
        stable[0].src = "../img/ne_bouge_pas_.gif";
    }
    // Collision personnage 
    //si la console affiche "collision" passer à la scène suivante    
    function isCollide(a, b) {
        var a = document.querySelector('.perso').getBoundingClientRect();
        var b = document.querySelector('.premierplan').getBoundingClientRect();
        // console.log(a);
        // console.log(b);
        if(
            ((a.y + a.height) < (b.y)) ||
            (a.y > (b.y + b.height)) ||
            ((a.x + a.width) < b.x) ||
            (a.x > (b.x + b.width))=== false && (e.keyCode == RIGHT_KEY)
        ){
            console.log("pas de collision");
        }
       
        else{
            console.log(" collision");
        };
        
    }
    isCollide()
};
    // console.log(e.keyCode);}

    //keycode

    document.onkeyup = function(e){//fonction quand la touche est relachée jouer l'animation 'ne_bouge_pas.gif"
        if(e.keyCode == LEFT_KEY){
            let stable = document.getElementsByClassName("perso");
            stable[0].src = "../img/ne_bouge_pas_.gif";
        }
        if(e.keyCode == RIGHT_KEY){
            let stable = document.getElementsByClassName("perso");
            stable[0].src = "../img/ne_bouge_pas_.gif";  }
            
            //collisions personnage page 1
            function isCollide(a, b) {
                var a = document.querySelector('.perso').getBoundingClientRect();
                var b = document.querySelector('.premierplan').getBoundingClientRect();
                // console.log(a);
                // console.log(b);
                if(
                    ((a.y + a.height) < (b.y)) ||
                    (a.y > (b.y + b.height)) ||
                    ((a.x + a.width) < b.x) ||
                    (a.x > (b.x + b.width)) === true && (e.keyCode == RIGHT_KEY)
                ){
                    console.log(" no collision");
                }
               
                else{
                    console.log("collision");//s'il est écrit  " collision"
                    window.location.href = '../html/page2.html';//passe à la page/scène suivante
                };
                
            }
            isCollide()//appel de la fonction     
    };
```

Thanks for your help. I hope that my answer will be useful for other developers for whom the code does not seem to work. Good day to you all